# How can I do an outer join with a group by in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have three tables in SQLite that were created from these classes. I joined these with the SQL below.

```
public class Phrase {
    [PrimaryKey, NotNull]
    public string PhraseId { get; set; }
    public int PhraseNum { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}
public class Category {
    [PrimaryKey, NotNull]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
public class CategoryGroup {
    [PrimaryKey, NotNull]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsToggled { get; set; }
}
```

So far I have this SQL

```
SELECT CG.NAME, COUNT(*) AS TotalPhraseCount 
FROM Phrase AS P
JOIN Category AS C ON P.CategoryId = C.Id
JOIN CategoryGroup AS CG ON C.GroupId = CG.Id
WHERE C.Selected = 1
GROUP BY C.GroupId
```

Which gives me as one of the Categories in Category group has 11 phrases and it's Selected:

```
CategoryGroupName PhrasesCount
A                 20
```

However what I need is to see every CategoryGroup row and a 0 if there are no Categories selected in that group. So for example this which includes the CategoryGroup B which has no Categories selected:

```
CategoryGroupName PhrasesCount
A                 20
B                 0
C                 0
```

I think I can do this with an outer join but I am not sure how to implement that in SQL.

Each category contains many phrases
Each category group contains many categories
Each category belongs to just one Category group
Each phrase belongs to just one Category

Hope that helps

Here's the output I have from Juan's query.  Not sure why there is a 1 in rows B and C

```
CategoryGroupName PhrasesCount
A                 20
B                 1
C                 1
```

Comment: Alan, please add sample data and the expected output.  Otherwise, you are asking us to guess.

Comment: The problem was you explain your problem backwards. You should said a Group has Categories, a Category has Phrases. That would tell you the order in which you have to join the tables and which one are on the `LEFT JOIN` side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CG.NAME, COUNT(C.GroupId) AS TotalPhraseCount 
FROM       CategoryGroup AS CG
LEFT JOIN  Category AS C 
       ON  CG.Id = C.GroupId
      AND  C.Selected = 1                         
LEFT JOIN  Phrase AS P 
       ON P.CategoryId = C.Id
GROUP BY CG.NAME
```

Comment: This is another guest, just post the sample data and expected output next time

Comment: This one almost works but for some reason gives a TotalPhraseCount of 1 in those categoryGroups that have no selected categories.

Comment: Try again. `Count(C.GroupId)` will ignore null rows

Answer (score 1):

Use left join

```
SELECT CG.NAME, COUNT(*) AS TotalPhraseCount 
FROM Phrase AS P
left JOIN Category AS C ON P.CategoryId = C.Id
                       and C.Selected = 1
left JOIN CategoryGroup AS CG ON C.GroupId = CG.Id

GROUP BY C.GroupId
```

Comment: Tried that just now but it still only returns one row.  It doesn't return the row with B and 0 phrases.

Comment: @Alan2, you can check now - modified it a bit

Comment: just another bit :)

Comment: Your joins might be going in the wrong direction (not sure, as the OP gave us no sample data).

Comment: I think Category should be the first one. Otherwise you cant group by C.GroupID

Comment: Your last edit returns one row with A 20 and another row with null and 1732

Comment: @Alan2, provide some sample data - it will be easy to answer